# How to integrate Problem Steps Recorder (psr) in my application?

Tags: delphi, bug-reporting, problem-steps-recorder

Windows 7 has a wonderful facility called [problem steps recorder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
You can start it by typing `psr` on the command line.

[image]

What's the best way to integrate this into a Delphi application?
And is there a COM automation interface for psr?

I want to:

1. start the recorder from the program (easy: issue a command line and start it);
2. start recording automatically; (can this be done?)
3. Preset the filename `psr` will store the capture in; (how?)
4. Email the capture to an email address specified in my code.

If there's an alternative tool that does the same stuff I'd love to hear about that as well of course.
Because this is mainly a user-experience issue I'm not interested in automated crash reports, I know `madexcept` does a wonderful job on those.

I'm interested in seeing a slideshow where the user explains in 4 steps why feature x sucks or does not work as expected.

Comment: For those who are interested: `U+043C: CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EM`.

Comment: I am particularly interested in why Outlook works so well with PSR.  For example, Outlook shows green rectangles around the focused panes that the user typed some input into.

Comment: Interesting related information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744822.aspx   (UI Automation support in MS Common controls).  Having your app be more friendly to UI Automation would probably make it work better with PSR.  The thing that keeps me from loving PSR is its "willfull ignorance of keyboard text entry".

Comment: @NullUserException, thanks for trying to fix the title.

Comment: @Johan I know, it's a pain the behind: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so I undid everything  after I realized I wouldn't be able to retag it was all said and done.

Comment: I've used a different workaround for the time being.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be used from command line:

> psr.exe [/start |/stop][/output ] [/sc (0|1)] [/maxsc
>   ]
>       [/sketch (0|1)] [/slides (0|1)] [/gui (o|1)]
>       [/arcetl (0|1)] [/arcxml (0|1)] [/arcmht (0|1)]
>       [/stopevent ] [/maxlogsize ] [/recordpid ]

Here you can find more information about command line usage: [ctrlf5.net/?p=176](http://removed-phishing-url.com) **link removed as page 176 is now a nasty malware page**

And here is sample project which automates psr thorught command-line (c#): http://psr4vs.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/10645#172579

Comment: Way cool, when I type `psr /?` it gives an error though.  Ah well that's MS for ya.

Comment: @Johan - well this error says that you provided (`/?`) incorrect parameter, not that parameters are ignored. This was suspicious.

Comment: I just found the original post from Microsoft: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2011/10/04/a-custom-data-diagnostic-adapter-for-visual-studio-coded-ui-test-using-windows-psr.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Free alternative I can suggest is called [StepsToReproduce](http://stepstoreproduce.net). In many aspects it's much more usable - it allows several options for recording (screen/window/region) and has powerful annotation tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a desktop icon whose target points to a .BAT file where you launch the PSR tool first, then launch your application, and upon application closure, stop the recorder.
e.g.

```
@ECHO OFF
START /B PSR.EXE /START /OUTPUT "[outFilePath]" /SC 1 /MAXSC 25 /GUI 0
CALL "[pathToYourApp]"
PSR.EXE /STOP
```

Comment: Yes, obviously, but that's hardly integration.